# How do I replicate the same column values for the next 2 cells in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to replicate the same column values for the next 2 cells in the column using R.

I have a data-frame of the following form:

```
Time      World   Cate   Data
1994     Africa     A      12  
1994                B      17
1994                C      22
1994       Asia     A      55
1994                B      10
1994                C      58
1995     Africa     A      62  
1995                B      87
1995                C      12
1995       Asia     A      59
1995                B      12
1995                C      38
```

and I want to convert it to the following form:

```
Time      World   Cate   Data
1994     Africa     A      12  
1994     Africa     B      17
1994     Africa     C      22
1994       Asia     A      55
1994       Asia     B      10
1994       Asia     C      58
1995     Africa     A      62  
1995     Africa     B      87
1995     Africa     C      12
1995       Asia     A      59
1995       Asia     B      12
1995       Asia     C      38
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fill` from the `tidyr` package:

If your dataframe is called `dat`, then

```
dat <- tidyr::fill(dat, World)
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work

Comment: it should do, that is what `fill` is for.  what is the error message or output that you get?

Answer (score 1):

Using `na.locf` function from `library(zoo)`

```
library(zoo)

na.locf(df)

   Time  World Cate Data
1  1994 Africa    A   12
2  1994 Africa    B   17
3  1994 Africa    C   22
4  1994   Asia    A   55
5  1994   Asia    B   10
6  1994   Asia    C   58
7  1995 Africa    A   62
8  1995 Africa    B   87
9  1995 Africa    C   12
10 1995   Asia    A   59
11 1995   Asia    B   12
12 1995   Asia    C   38
```

## Code

```
dummy$World <- rep(dummy$World[(1:floor(dim(dummy)[1]/5))*5-4],each = 5)
dummy
```

Comment: This is working, but there are other issues. My actual data frame doesn't look as clean as this example. Some of my inputs in  "Data" also have NA values.

Comment: @Maharrnab Does `World` variable is clean? Or it's also unclean?

Comment: what do you mean by clean

Comment: @Maharrnab I add the new code. **Clean** means that `World` have every first values from the first row and exist by three rows after.

Comment: Yes, but the first few(5) rows have empty values. But I am basically cutting that part out and putting it back later

Comment: @Maharrnab Then does my new code works for your real data?

Comment: No it is giving something very different

Comment: @Maharrnab Explanation about your data may not enough.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239448/discussion-between-maharrnab-and-park).