# repeating a row to fill in missing row values in R

Tags: r, database, dataframe

I have a dataset that looks like this

| left | center | right |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | data | data |
|  | data | data |
|  | data | data |
|  | data | data |
| Two | data | data |
|  | data | data |
|  | data | data |
|  | data | data |
| Three | data | data |
|  | data | data |
|  | data | data |
|  | data | data |

What I need it to do is to look like this

| left | center | right |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | data | data |
| One | data | data |
| One | data | data |
| One | data | data |
| Two | data | data |
| Two | data | data |
| Two | data | data |
| Two | data | data |
| Three | data | data |
| Three | data | data |
| Three | data | data |
| Three | data | data |

The core issue as you can see is that I have a single value that is only within one row but needs to be in all the associated rows.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70062392/how-do-i-replicate-the-same-column-values-for-the-next-2-cells-in-r

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fill function from the tidyr library

```
fill(dataset, left , .direction = "down")
```